# How to get all connections since a certain time period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get all connections (interactions) on a facebook page since a certain time period. I'm using the koala gem and filtering the request with "since: 1.month.ago.to_i" which seems to work fine. However, this gives me 25 results at a time. If I change the limit to 446 (the maximum it seems) that works better. But...if I use .next_page to give me the next set of results within the given time range, it instead just gives me a next set of results without obeying the time range.

For example, let's say I don't increase the limit and I have 25 results per request. I do something like:

```
@api.get_connections(@fan_page_id, "feed", {since: 1.month.ago.to_i})
```

let's assume there are 30 results for this and the first request gets me 25 (the default limit). then, if I do this:

```
@api.get_connections(@fan_page_id, "feed", {since: 1.month.ago.to_i}).next_page
```

instead of returning the last 5 results, it returns 25 more, 20 of which are not "since: 1.month.ago.to_i". I have a while loop cycling through the pages but I don't know where to stop since it just keep returning results to me no matter what as long as I keep calling .next_page.

1. is there a better way of doing this?
2. if not, what's the best way to check to make sure the post i'm looking at in the loop is still within the time range i want and to break out if not?

here's my code:

```
  def perform(fan_page_id, pagination_options = {})
    @since_date = pagination_options[:since_date] if pagination_options[:since_date]
    @limit = pagination_options[:limit] if pagination_options[:limit]

    @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new
    @api = Koala::Facebook::API.new @oauth.get_app_access_token

    fb_page = @api.get_object(fan_page_id)
    @fan_page_id = fb_page["id"]

    # Collect all the users who liked, commented, or liked *and* commented on a post
    process_posts(@api.get_connections(@fan_page_id, "feed", {since: @since_date})) do |post|

      ## do stuff based on each post

    end
  end


  private
    # Take each post from the specified feed and perform the provided
    # code on each post in that feed.
    #
    # @param [Koala::Facebook::API::GraphCollection] feed An API response containing a page's feed
    def process_posts(feed, options = {})
      raise ArgumentError unless block_given?

      current_feed = feed

      begin

        current_feed.each { |post| yield(post) }
        current_feed = current_feed.next_page

      end while current_feed.any?
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 current  =  @api.get_connections(@fan_page_id, "feed", {since: 1.month.ago.to_i})

 next = current.next_page

 next = next.next_page 

 .....
```

Please try these, I think they work.